# Не работает таймер появления текста

Tags: java, android, textview

Попытался сделать таймер, а по его истечению попытался сделать поялвение текста, но получаю ошибку, что делать?
Код

```
package com.culturehappyhour.bluearcher.plug;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.culturehappyhour.bluearcher.R;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Progress extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView ok1;
    TextView ok2;
    TextView ok3;
    TextView ok4;
    TextView ok5;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_progress);


        ok1 = findViewById(R.id.ok1);
        ok2 = findViewById(R.id.ok2);
        ok3 = findViewById(R.id.ok3);
        ok4 = findViewById(R.id.ok4);
        ok5 = findViewById(R.id.ok5);

        Timer timer1 = new Timer();
        timer1.schedule(new UpdateTimeTaskOk1(), 10000, 10000);//for ok1

        Timer timer2 = new Timer();
        timer2.schedule(new UpdateTimeTaskOk2(), 10000, 10000);//for ok2

        Timer timer3 = new Timer();
        timer3.schedule(new UpdateTimeTaskOk3(), 10000, 10000);//for ok3

        Timer timer4 = new Timer();
        timer4.schedule(new UpdateTimeTaskOk4(), 10000, 10000);//for ok4

        Timer timer5 = new Timer();
        timer5.schedule(new UpdateTimeTaskOk5(), 10000, 10000);//for ok5

    }

    class UpdateTimeTaskOk1 extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {
            ok1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
    class UpdateTimeTaskOk2 extends TimerTask{
        public void run(){
            ok2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    class UpdateTimeTaskOk3 extends TimerTask{
        public void run(){
            ok3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    class UpdateTimeTaskOk4 extends TimerTask{
        public void run(){
            ok4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    class UpdateTimeTaskOk5 extends TimerTask{
        public void run(){
            ok5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }


}
```

Ошибка

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
    Process: com.culturehappyhour.bluearcher, PID: 10850
    android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:8191)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.focusableViewAvailable(ViewRootImpl.java:4109)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:940)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:940)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:940)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:940)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:940)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:940)
        at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:15181)
        at android.view.View.setVisibility(View.java:10836)
        at com.culturehappyhour.bluearcher.plug.Progress$UpdateTimeTaskOk1.run(Progress.java:52)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:562)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:512)
```

Comment: Обращение к View должно происходить на MainThread. [Вот подробнее тред на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738239/android-accessing-ui-element-from-timer-thread)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ошибке вашей написано, что вы пытаетесь изменить View не в главном потоке. Чтобы изменения делать в главном потоке:

Вместо:

> ok1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Напишите так:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            ok1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо)